# Populating XmlAnyAttribute in WCF Client

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF client created for a SOAP service that contains the following type in its schema:

```
<xs:element name="foo" nillable="true">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And .NET generates the following class:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1098.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://example.com/ws/entity")]
public partial class foo : object {

  private string barField;

  private System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] anyAttrField;

  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
  public string bar {
    get { return this.barField; }
    set { this.barField = value; }
  }

  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyAttributeAttribute()]
  public System.Xml.XmlAttribute[] AnyAttr {
    get { return this.anyAttrField; }
    set { this.anyAttrField = value; }
  }
}
```

What is the recommended way to populate the AnyAttr property on this class? The only way that I can find to create an `XmlAttribute` is from an existing `XmlDocument`, which in this case isn't created until the object is serialized on its way out.

I started trying to add an attribute to the element in `BeforeSendRequest` in an `IClientMessageInspector`, but the only way I could find to modify the raw `XmlDocument` was to create a copy of the `Message`, transform it, then replace the original message, which seemed like a lot of work just to add an attribute.

Ultimately, I'm trying to create XML that looks like:

```
...
  <foo xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/ws/ext" ns2:other="some other value">
    <bar>some value</bar>
  </foo>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do own the service where `Foo` is defined, and while I cannot modify `Foo` itself, I am able to add custom elements to the schema. So instead of trying to the existing `xs:anyAttribute` in the schema, I added a new element for my data.